# How to evaluate datetime expression in JSON File?

Tags: c#, .net, json, jint

1. I have Json File like below:

   ```
                   {
                       "Country": "QAT",
                       "Rules": "if(BO.SenderCountryId == 'QAT' && BO.SenderIdExpiryDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-90)){true}",
                       "ErrorKey": "BusinessErrExpiryDateInvalid"
                   }
   ```
2. want to run above json Key "Rules" in c# using JINT:

   ```
   Engine engine = new Engine();
               engine.SetValue("BO", BO);
               foreach (JProperty item in Rule)
               {
                   if (item.Name.Equals("Rules"))
                   {
                       engine.Execute(Convert.ToString(item.Value));
                       bool validated = (bool)engine.GetCompletionValue().ToObject();
                   }
               }
   ```
3. Getting Error "DateTime is not defined" .It would be helpful If someone can help me to understand can it possible to use DateTime object in JSON using JINT

Comment: Isn't JINT a javascript interpreter? If so, it probably doesnt have the System.DateTime class available, which is a .NET class. you could try to make a valid javascript code for jint, for example by trying it out here: https://playcode.io/603110/

Comment: ok thanks, i will try on that.